# UITableView Cell Redirect

Tags: uitableview

I am creating an UITableView and has a question on how to redirect the user to a new view when the person clicks on the cell. It would helpful if could provide some code and possible an explanation. Thank you :)

ViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>  {


    IBOutlet UIButton *Startbutton;


}

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *array;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        Startbutton.layer.cornerRadius = 5; // this value vary as per your desire
        Startbutton.clipsToBounds = YES;

        //Status Bar
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

        //Array
        self.array = [[ NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];

    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    -(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
        return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    }

    //Array Main Code
    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

        return 1;

    }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.array.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellID = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];

    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell; 

}




@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pretty basic way of doing this without having to write code at all, but I am not sure if it is exactly what you want, sorry if it doesn't help.

Drag in a UITableViewController, in the Attributes inspector, select **Static Cells** from the 'Content' drop down box. Then add how ever many cells you like, click on the cell, then under the  attributes inspector change the 'Style' to whatever you like and then change the content of the cell. Then all you have to do to link that cell to a new view is; right click the cell and drag your cursor to the destination view, then Select Modal (or Push if you are in a navigation controller).

That way when you run the app and click on that cell you should be switched to the new view.

No coding is required at all.

Hoped that helped in someway.

Cheers